# Cisco Phone Status ASP.NET integration

Tags: asp.net, .net, phone-call, cisco, tapi

We're trying to find a way to retrieve information about when an employee is currently on the phone.

The phones we use are Cisco IP Phone 7945 brand with CallManager 7.1.30000-1 and we were wanting to integrate it with asp.net. We want to be able to know when an employee's phone is off the hook.

We have gone to http://developer.cisco.com, but we are uncertain on which API or SDK to use. We have tried AXL but it doesn't do what we're looking for.

Is TAPI/JTAPI the way to go? Is there an example to get started for .NET?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what TAPI/JTAPI can do, but we just query the callmanager database directly to get that kind of information.